# How to add ARP functionality to snull devices?

Tags: linux, networking

I need to connect two PC with Network Device Driver. The snull driver (http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) work only into one PC. Could you help me?

I have studied the cap.17 of the book "Linux Device Drivers, 3rd Edition by Jonathan Corbet, Alessandro Rubini", but nothing.

I have create two snull device sn0 and sn1. The command "ifconfig" see the new networks, but the command "arp -a" doesn't see the networks...

I have used the command "nmcli device show" and the sn0 network haven't the gateway set.

I'd like to ping the sn0 network from another PC link to it.
TIA

Comment: Afaik `snull` is a stub to develop network device drivers on a local machine. Why are you specifically using snull when you want to connect two PCs? Why not go for a regular IP network setup?

Comment: I need to make a network where I need to modify the traffic... so a regular IP networking setup doesn't work.

Comment: reading chapter 17: "Another feature of snull is that it supports only IP traffic." ARP is not IP. Later `dev->flags|= IFF_NOARP;` which is consistent with layer 3 interfaces lacking ARP. The Ethernet equivalent is `veth` which was added around Linux 2.6.24 later than this chapter 17 (on lwn: "LDD3 is current as of the 2.6.10 kernel.").

Comment: Neither is suited to connect two PC afaik, but veth is suited to connect two network namespaces.

Comment: I just try veth but I need to modify the traffic so it isn't for me.